# Targeting svg elements with d3 mouse event handling

Tags: javascript, svg, event-handling, d3.js

I'm trying to make a horizontal d3 line graph with hover over capabilities, but I'm running into trouble with overlaying SVG elements. I'm relatively new to javascript as a whole, but I am trying to pass the mouseover event to the actual bars of the chart, and instead they are being absorbed by the 'summary2' element. I tried setting the `pointer-events: none;` for that element, but no luck. I've also tried various groupings within the elements. My fiddle is here:  [Bar chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmoore38/xurDA/7/) . I'm just trying to toggle the class of the bars on mouseover. Thank you! And a big thanks to Mike with all the available documentation

Comment: There is no `mouseover` element because the bars are obscured by the elements that you create later. If you add the bars (and the group that contains them) at the end, it works.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the quick reply and quick fix! I'll need to read up more on my javascript.

Comment: No problem. That should have read "event" instead of "element" BTW :)